# magento2.4.5 Static files do not recognize upper and lower case letters

Tags: magento2, varnish

Multi-store, open static file signature, after using varnish, magento2 language has larger letters, template directory letters are case indistinguishable. for example
it_IT is parsed as it_it, and en_US is parsed as en_us, resulting in unreadable static files. The log reports the following error:

```
[2022-09-08T12:54:31.805983+00:00] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Enerart/enerart/en_US/Magepow_Productzoom/js/plugins/jquery.elevatezoom.min.js' [ ] []
[2022-09-08T12:54:31.806132+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Enerart/enerart/en_US/Magepow_Productzoom/js/plugins/jquery.elevatezoom.min.js' [ ] []
[2022-09-08T13:18:41.869232+00:00] main.ERROR: Requested path '_cache/merged/ca17785e623f3fe2334ae29c293cd547.js' is wrong. [] []
[2022-09-08T13:18:41.869417+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Requested path '_cache/merged/ca17785e623f3fe2334ae29c293cd547.js' is wrong. [] []
[2022-09-08T13:31:35.422676+00:00] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Enerart/enerart/ja_JP/fonts/electro/fonts/font-electro.ttf' [] [ ]
[2022-09-08T13:31:35.422879+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Enerart/enerart/ja_JP/fonts/electro/fonts/font-electro.ttf' [] [ ]
[2022-09-08T13:42:45.249685+00:00] main.ERROR: Requested path frontend/enerart/enerart/it_it/mage/requirejs/static.min.js is wrong. [] []
```